# How can i make sure this while loop can rerun my random number code without going forever?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I created a guess the number program and used a while loop to allow the user to continue guessing until he/she could get it right, as seen here:

```
import random

number = random.randrange(1, 6) 

print "Guess the number, between 1 and 6"

guess = "yes"

while guess != number: 
    guess = int(raw_input('>'))
    if guess == number:
        break
        print "Good job! You got it right!"
        print number 


    elif guess > number: 
        print "Too High"
        print number  
        number = random.randrange(1, 6) 

    elif guess < number:
        print "Too Low"
        print number  
        number = random.randrange(1, 6)
```

The problem is, when I am trying to guess the number, it will randomly end, whether me guessing the first time, 4 times, or 30 times. Also, I originally had,

```
guess = int(raw_input('>'))
```

in place of,

```
guess = "yes"
```

and replaced it to get rid of the extra and useless raw_input i'd initially need to add into terminal. Why am i able to make it equal "yes" and why doesn't it matter what I put there?

Example of Bug:

```
Guess the number, between 1 and 6
>3
Too High
2
>4
Too Low
5
>6
Too High
5
>3
Too High
1
>2
Too High
1
>5
Good job! You got it right!
5


------------------
(program exited with code: 0)
Press return to continue
```

It worked that time, and now:

```
Guess the number, between 1 and 6
>3
Too Low
4


------------------
(program exited with code: 0)
Press return to continue
```

Comment: put the break after all the print stmts.

Comment: Do you mean to change the number after every wrong guess?

Comment: Is that code in your question the _entire exact_ script you ran to get that output?

Comment: Yup, and i think it got fixed, i needed to include the input under the while loop.

Comment: No it wasn't :). There's no way the current code you have there gave that output.

Comment: Oh oops, the break was under the prints in the if statements but thats it

Comment: I found the problem, but it seems Blckknght already did :).

Comment: You shouldn't add "(Solved)" to the question title; you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that your `while` loop is testing if `number` matched `guess` *after* picking a new `number` value but before getting a new `guess`. This means that you'll say the player guessed wrong, but they they become right afterwards and the loop will end.

Try this instead:

```
import random

print "Guess the number, between 1 and 6"

guess = 'y' # the values set here don't actually matter, they just need to be different
number = 'x'

while guess != number: 
    number = random.randint(1, 6) 
    guess = int(raw_input('>'))

    if guess == number:
        print "Good job! You got it right!"

    elif guess > number: 
        print "Too High"
        print number  

    elif guess < number:
        print "Too Low"
        print number
```

I've also changed your use of `random.randrange` to `random.randint`, which will make it actually return `6`s some of the time (`randrange` excludes the upper bound).

Comment: Thank you for the help! Means a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

number = random.randrange(1, 6) 

print "Guess the number, between 1 and 6"

guess = "yes"

while guess != number: 
    guess = int(raw_input('>'))
    if guess == number:
        break
        print "Good job! You got it right!"
        print number 
        break


    elif guess > number: 
        print "Too High"
        print number  
        number = random.randrange(1, 6) 
        break

    elif guess < number:
        print "Too Low"
        print number  
        number = random.randrange(1, 6) 
        break
```

Comment: I'm not actually trying to break after one try, i'm allowing the program to run until my guess = the random number, which changes after every input.

Answer (score 0):

`guess = "yes"` works because `guess != number` will always be `True` on the first check in the while loop, at which point the user is asked for input. Also, in the `if` block, put the `break` statement after all the `print`'s.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i tried that too, still the same problem occurs. I believe it may be a bug that is outside my code, that randomly chooses when to stop the program, even if my guess did not equal the number. Anyway, thank you also for the yes explanation, it makes sense.

Comment: @Asparique, can you clarify what's going on? Are you sure that the program is stopping even when you don't guess the number? Is it only stopping when you make a guess? Perhaps you could include in your question a session of the program that shows the bug.

Comment: Sure thing, just did @Cyphase